# Restrict users to recieve emails once they exit from journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a requirement in which users should not get any emails for 2 months once they exit journey. In journey settings we have used "re-enter only after exiting the journey". Is there a way we can achieve this?

Thanks
R

Comment: do you mean ANY emails - User Initiated, send wizard, triggered, journey, etc? Or just they should not be entered into any further journeys for 2 months?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are injecting your users into the journey.  There are many Entry Source options.

For your requirement, without knowing the journey purpose or goal, the one that I can think of is Data Extension entry.  I would develop a SQL Query activity and filter out the users who have been in the journey mentioned in the last two months.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in multiple ways depending on your use case and potential change to your journey logic. Some of the solutions you can use are these :

- Use the "re-enter only after exiting the journey" combined with a wait activity that would keep your contacts in the Journey for 2 months.
- Implemant an "Update Contact" activity with the `{{Contact.Key}}` data binding that would log your contacts into a "Journey History" Data extension with a **2 month data retention period of time** and then using in your journey entry a filter (or a decision split) that would check if contacts have already entered the journey in the last 2 months
- Using the same solution as idea number 2, but this time using an SQL to exclude contact in your "Journey History" Data Extension.

And as I said, the solution you would choose must be a best fit to your Campaign logic.